# Loop through multiple .txt files in the folder (using glob) and combine them

Tags: python, glob

I'm new to Python and have a task which is partly working, would appreciate some support.

**Task:** Loop through multiple .txt files in the data folder (using glob) and combine them into a dictionary

For each file, do the following:

1. Open it
2. Extract the data into a dictionary as in the previous task
3. Add the dictionary onto the holder list

**Here is my code so far but the output is blank**

```
from glob import glob
import os.path

# make an empty list to hold the data
holder = []
key = ["id","age","gender"]

# for each text file in the data folder,
for filepath in glob("data/*.txt"):
   
 #load the file
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        data = file.read().split()
        dictionary = dict(zip(key, file))
    holder.append(dictionary)

print(holder)
```

**The output shows:**
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]

**Here is what 1 of the text files looks like:**
[image]

**Here is another image of the update code, its almost there in terms of layout but it has the same data for each dictionary, it doesn't seems to be going through all the files.**
[image]

Comment: What's the link between `key` and file contents?

Comment: There appear to be some indentation problems in your posted code. Please correct the code sample and ensure that it is runnable.

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of the code. (2) What should `data = file.read().split()` do?

Comment: is the `data` variable used at all? is it normal that you are using the `file` object in your dictionnary ?

Comment: @ahmed the key represents the data in each text file and order its in

Comment: @larsks indentation fixed, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to do something like this:

```
from glob import glob
import os.path

# make an empty list to hold the data
holder = []
key = ["id","age","gender"]

# for each text file in the data folder,
for filepath in glob("data/*.txt"):

 #load the file
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        rows = file.read().split("\n")
        for row in rows:
            data = row.split(",")
            holder.append(dict(zip(key, data)))

print(holder)
```

So you have to somehow iterate over the rows and append the data to the holder.

So `for row in file:` would also be possible but in this case you have to handle eol (\n at least if you treat it as a text file) as well.

**Update**
With the new Information I think you only have to replace the `data Variable` in the zip function with rows.

```
...
 #load the file
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        rows = file.read().split("\n")
        #for row in rows:
            #data = row.split(",")
            holder.append(dict(zip(key, rows)))

print(holder)
```

Comment: Thanks @deiserh that's very close to what I want, except its assigning all values the "id" key. Each file contains "id","age","gender" as per the key so the needs to reflect in the outcome. Here is what the outcome looks like: [{'id': '28'}, {'id': '42'}, {'id': 'F'}]

Comment: Can you share an example file?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add a file but I've added an image to main question and here is an example of what one looks like once opened:
28
42
F

Comment: @user3442162 is in one txt file only one entry (three rows) or is it possible that one txt file contains multiple entries?

Comment: @deiserh each file contains only a single set of data, thank you for the update its worked perfectly